# Desktop IE11 thinks it's a mobile browser (and grabs mobile media query css)

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating an angular site, it and it has a lightbox. When the lightbox opens, and the browser's width is over 978px, it should give the lightbox a width of 600px. Works fine in Chrome and FF, but in IE, it instead grabs the media query and makes the width 100%. HOWEVER when I resize the browser, it grabs to correct styles.

```
@media (max-width: 395px) {
   #sgf_form {
        width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Is this a known bug and what's the workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewport for IE10 & 11 desktop, but not mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659053/viewport-for-ie10-11-desktop-but-not-mobile)

Comment: Could we have all the media queries, please?

Comment: `max-width` refers to the window size. Did you mean the screen size, `max-device-width`?